# PyQt5 Перевод из двоичного кода в .png / .txt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Графику создавал с *Qt Designer*.

**main.py**

```
import struct
import numpy
import random
import scipy
from scipy.stats import laplace
import math
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from model import Ui_model


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.data = None
        self.setFixedSize(896, 662)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_IS)

    def on_clicked_IS(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './')  # Файлы (*.txt *.log, *.png, *.docx)

        _bit = 0
        _byte = 0
        if fname:
            print()
            if fname.endswith("docx"):
                print("docx")
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.read()
                    a = 0

                    for x in str(self.data):
                        a += (len(list((format(ord(x), '08b')))))
                    print(a)  # биты
                    b = a / 8  # байты
                    print(math.ceil(b))
                    _bit = a
                    _byte = math.ceil(b)


            elif fname.endswith("png") or fname.endswith("jpg"):  # Расчёт битов и байтов для картинки
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.read()
                    d = 0
                    for x in str(self.data):
                        d += (len(list((format(ord(x), '08b')))))
                    print(d)  # биты
                    b = d / 8  # байты
                    print(math.ceil(b))
                    _bit = d
                    _byte = math.ceil(b)


            elif fname.endswith("txt") or fname.endswith("log"):  # Расчёт битов и байтов для *.txt / *.log
                with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.readlines()

                    c = 0
                    for x in str(self.data):
                        c += (len(list((format(ord(x), '08b')))))
                    print(c)  # биты
                    b = c / 8  # байты
                    print(math.ceil(b))
                    _bit = c
                    _byte = math.ceil(b)

            if _bit:  # +++
                self.lineEdit.setText(str(_bit))

            if _byte:  # +++
                self.lineEdit_9.setText(str(_byte))


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**model.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_model(object):
    def setupUi(self, model):
        model.setObjectName("model")
        model.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        model.setEnabled(True)
        model.resize(889, 753)
        model.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 127);\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(model)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 490, 181, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 87 10pt \"Segoe UI Black\";")
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 480, 871, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 541, 401))
        self.label_19.setText("")
        self.label_19.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/dim4i/Downloads/11.PNG"))
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 570, 221, 61))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 245, 219);\n"
"font: 87 10pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 245, 219);\n"
"font: 87 10pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 481, 101))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget1)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_15, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_9, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_14, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_13, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_7.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_5.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_3.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_8.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_12, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_9.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_6.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_16, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 510, 382, 48))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_17, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget2)
        self.lineEdit_11.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_18, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget2)
        self.lineEdit_10.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 420, 211, 65))
        self.widget3.setObjectName("widget3")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget3)
        self.checkBox.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 3, 15);")
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget3)
        self.checkBox_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget3)
        self.checkBox_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 20, 191, 38))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 87 10pt \"Segoe UI Black\";")
        self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.widget4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 90, 251, 201))
        self.widget4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 201))
        self.widget4.setObjectName("widget4")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget4)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.label_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(154, 18))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.doubleSpinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget4)
        self.doubleSpinBox_2.setMaximum(10.0)
        self.doubleSpinBox_2.setSingleStep(0.01)
        self.doubleSpinBox_2.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.doubleSpinBox_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.doubleSpinBox_4 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget4)
        self.doubleSpinBox_4.setMaximum(9600.0)
        self.doubleSpinBox_4.setSingleStep(0.01)
        self.doubleSpinBox_4.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.doubleSpinBox_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.doubleSpinBox_5 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget4)
        self.doubleSpinBox_5.setMaximum(200.0)
        self.doubleSpinBox_5.setSingleStep(0.01)
        self.doubleSpinBox_5.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.doubleSpinBox_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.doubleSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget4)
        self.doubleSpinBox.setMaximum(10.0)
        self.doubleSpinBox.setSingleStep(0.01)
        self.doubleSpinBox.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.doubleSpinBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget4)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget4)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(618, 303, 181, 61))
        self.widget5.setObjectName("widget5")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget5)
        self.gridLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget5)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 245, 219);\n"
"font: 87 10pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget5)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 245, 219);\n"
"font: 87 10pt \"Segoe UI Black\";")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_11, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_10, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        model.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(model)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        model.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.action_5 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_5.setObjectName("action_5")
        self.action_6 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_6.setObjectName("action_6")
        self.action_7 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_7.setObjectName("action_7")

        self.retranslateUi(model)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(model)

    def retranslateUi(self, model):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        model.setWindowTitle(_translate("model", "Модель Рос - АП"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("model", "Результат испытания"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("model", "START"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("model", "STOP"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("model", "Коэффициент ошибки"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("model", "Биты"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("model", "Ошибки"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("model", "Блоки"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("model", "Байты"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("model", "Принято"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("model", "Скорость передачи полезной информации, Бод"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("model", "Количество повторений искажённых блоков"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("model", "Моделирование в реальном времени"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("model", "Моделировать аварию"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("model", "Анимация передачи"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("model", "Параметры испытания"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("model", "Повторы искажённых блоков"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("model", "Скорость передачи, Бод"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("model", "Размер блока, байт"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("model", "Уровень шума, В"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("model", "Уровень полезного сигнала, В"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("model", "Частота шума, Кгц"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("model", "8"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("model", "32"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("model", "64"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("model", "128"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("model", "256"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("model", "512"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("model", "1024"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("model", "0"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("model", "1"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("model", "2"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("model", "3"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("model", "4"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(5, _translate("model", "5"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(6, _translate("model", "6"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(7, _translate("model", "7"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(8, _translate("model", "8"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(9, _translate("model", "9"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(10, _translate("model", "10"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("model", "ИС"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("model", "ПС"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("model", "Приёмник сигнала"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("model", "Источник сигнала"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("model", "Сохранить"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("model", "Открыть"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("model", "Выйти"))
        self.action_5.setText(_translate("model", "Выйти из программы"))
        self.action_6.setText(_translate("model", "Выбрать источник сигнала"))
        self.action_7.setText(_translate("model", "Выбрать приёмник сигнала"))
```

И так, программа при нажатии на кнопку 'ИС' открывает в зависимости от расширения (`1.txt / 1.png / 1.docx`) файл,
считывает его и переводит в байты и биты.

Вопрос: как сделать обратный перевод, байты и биты обратно в картинку или текст?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перевод из двоичного кода в `png` / `txt` - можно сделать так:

```
import struct
import numpy
import random
import scipy
from scipy.stats import laplace
import math
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from model import Ui_model


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.data = None
        self.setFixedSize(896, 662)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_IS)

    def on_clicked_IS(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './')  

        _bit = 0
        _byte = 0
        if fname:
            print()
            if fname.endswith("docx"):          
                print("docx")
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.read()
                    a = 0

                    for x in str(self.data):
                        a += (len(list((format(ord(x), '08b')))))
                    print(a)  # биты
                    b = a / 8  # байты
                    print(math.ceil(b))
                    _bit = a
                    _byte = math.ceil(b)
            elif fname.endswith("png") or fname.endswith("jpg"):  
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.read()
                    d = 0
                    for x in str(self.data):
                        d += (len(list((format(ord(x), '08b')))))
                    print(d)  # биты
                    b = d / 8  # байты
                    print(math.ceil(b))
                    _bit = d
                    _byte = math.ceil(b)
# +++  png  or jpg vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv               
                image = QtGui.QImage.fromData(self.data)
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
                self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
                self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                self.label.show()                    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            elif fname.endswith("txt") or fname.endswith("log"):  
                with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.readlines()

                    c = 0
                    for x in str(self.data):
                        c += (len(list((format(ord(x), '08b')))))
                    print(c)  # биты
                    b = c / 8  # байты
                    print(math.ceil(b))
                    _bit = c
                    _byte = math.ceil(b)
                
# +++ txt vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
                    self._data = fh.read()  
                # print(self._data)                    
                # print(self._data.decode())
                self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
                self.label.setText(self._data.decode())
                self.label.show() 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            if _bit:  
                self.lineEdit.setText(str(_bit))

            if _byte:  
                self.lineEdit_9.setText(str(_byte))


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не так поняли.Создаётся новый файл этого же типа(картинки) и переводятся эти биты и байты в картинку

Comment: @Bokan23 я ответил на ваш вопрос и показал вам как это можно сделать.

Comment: Нужно перевести картинку, сохраненную в формате png в новый файл в двоичный код. И я не говорил её открывать